# $\lim\limits_{y \rightarrow 0}\frac{y}{e^y-1}$ Without L'Hospital and Derivative

Tags: calculus

$$\lim_{y \rightarrow 0}\frac{y}{e^y-1}$$

while revising old scripts I have seen this task. By that date we only had continuity as basis no derivatives. How could this be calculated without using derivative or L'Hospital's rule. With L'Hospital's rule, it would be easy-going. Appreciate your help. Maybe the professor did not elaborate on that, due to this fact, and wrote it simply as given.

EDIT:
Well, the original task was $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\log(x+1)}{x}$ and he substituted $y=\log(x+1)$

ANOTHER Question, which will give me the proof. IF $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0}f(x)=L\$$ then $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0}\frac{1}{f(x)}=1/L$ ?

Comment: How did you define $e^y$? That's a key aspect here.

Comment: The edit is not answering my question. There are multiple ways to define the exponential function (and they can be shown to be equivalent, but that's not necessarily trivial). Which one did your teacher use?

Comment: It was not meant for you, i was checking that up. He introduced as a series

Comment: Did you try substituting the series for $e^y$ and simplifying? That does it almost instantly.

Comment: i dont know exactly what you mean?

Comment: $e^y=1+y+y^2/2+\cdots$

Comment: i would still have $0/0$ which wouldnt change anything..

Comment: The limit of a quotient is equal to the quotient of the limits if the limit of the denominator is non-zero

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thanks a lot mate.

Comment: It might be "unnecessary" since the question has been answered by you can see that limit as the a form of $\frac{1}{f'(0)}$ where $f(y)=exp(y)$. I just want to give another point of view to solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note $e^y=1+y+O(y^2)$

$$\lim_{y \rightarrow 0}\frac{y}{e^y-1}
= \lim_{y \rightarrow 0}\frac{y}{y+O(y^2)} 
= \lim_{y \rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{1+O(y)}  =1$$

Comment: Thanks solved it a bit differenlty using the series and showing that $(e^x-1)/x$ goes to 1 for x to 0. and by using that if lim f(x)=L lim 1/f(x)=1/L i got the answer but thanks a lot

Comment: I really am not convinced that, if they haven't the derivatives at their disposal, they have Taylor expansions and Peano's remainder theorem.

Answer (score 0):

You could approximate $e^y$ With the first three terms of the power series and observe that $\frac{1+y}{e^y}<\frac{y}{e^y-1}<\frac{y}{1+y+\frac{y^2}{2!}-1}$. Then reduce the ones at denominator and simplify by y to observe the right term tends to 1. As for the far left term, I just built it by increasing the denominator and fitting the numerator.

Answer (score 0):

Suddenly, you question made me remembering a trick my professor gave us in almost the same context.

Close to $0$
$$e^y \sim \frac {2+y}{2-y}$$ then
$$\frac{y}{e^y-1} \sim \frac y {\frac {2+y}{2-y}-1}=1-\frac y 2$$ which not only shows the limit but also how it is approached.